# Javascript move objects in a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that is defined like this:

```
const arr = [
  {
    status: 'status1',
    count: 2,
    elements: [
      {
        id: '1',
      },
      {
        id: '2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    status: 'status2',
    count: 1,
    elements: [
      {
        id: '3',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    status: 'status3',
    count: 1,
    elements: [
      {
        id: '4',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

The array is dynamic, but I know the `status` field and the `id` inside the elements. What I am trying to achieve is a new array, that contains all the same items, but looks like this instead:

```
const arr = [
  {
    status: 'status1',
    count: 1,
    elements: [
      {
        id: '1',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    status: 'status2',
    count: 2,
    elements: [
      {
        id: '2',
      },
      {
        id: '3',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    status: 'status3',
    count: 1,
    elements: [
      {
        id: '4',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

In other words, if `status === status1`, remove element with `id === 2`, set `count` to the length of `elements` array (or decrease by `1`), take the element that has `id === 2` and put it into `elements` array that has `status === status2`, set total `count` to the length of `elements` array .

I am not all that strong with iterating through nested elements and manipulating the array in these ways, but simpler concepts with `array.filter`/`map` etc seems okay, but I cannot wrap my head around all of this. :P

I would prefer to use vanilla JS, if possible. But I do have access to **lodash** if it makes things a lot easier.

---

**Edit**: When I mean vanilla JS, I refer to not using a ton of external libraries, but ES6 is what I use at this project.

My try consists of simply trying to filter `arr` on `status`, and then again on my `id`. Then I know what item I want to move. But it kind of stops there, and I also believe that it could be much more efficient:

```
const itemToMove = arr.filter(e => e.status === "status1")[0].elements.filter(e => e.id ==='2' )
```

I am not sure how to best proceed after this, thus asking for help.

Comment: at least, you could add your try ...

Comment: Where is the code that shows that you have tried to solve this yourself which we can improve upon? Also, when you say vanilla JS which version of ECMAS script do you consider vanilla?

Comment: I have edited my answer, but as I am not sure how to solve it, and I also belive that my filter().filter() could be much improved, I did not want to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the source and target objects and splice the element.

```js
const
    move = (data, from, to, id) => {
        const
            find = value => ({ status }) => status === value,
            source = data.find(find(from)),
            target = data.find(find(to)),
            index = source.elements.findIndex(o => o.id === id);
            
        if (index === -1) return;
        
        target.elements.push(...source.elements.splice(index, 1));
        source.count--;
        target.count++;
    },
    array = [{ status: 'status1', count: 2, elements: [{ id: '1' }, { id: '2' }] }, { status: 'status2', count: 1, elements: [{ id: '3' }] }, { status: 'status3', count: 1, elements: [{ id: '4' }] }];
   

move(array, 'status1', 'status2', '2');
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I asked for. It does also edit the original array, and my usecase cannot modify the original array, but I belive I can find a solution for that :) Thank you!